# Why is my difference in dates in bash resulting in a negative number?

Tags: bash, shell, date, sh, difference

When I obtain two date values and subtract them, sometimes I obtain a negative number:

```
start_time=$(date -u +%N)

#work

end_time=$(date -u +%N)
echo "execution time was $(expr $end_time - $start_time) s."
```

The work in between these date objects is doing an operation between two arrays in SciDB (for example, multiplication of two 100x100 arrays). This operation in different cases can take less than a second, which is why I use nanoseconds.
Example outputs:

```
computer@place:~/some-scripts$ ./test_mult_100.sh
execution time was 273467147 s.
computer@place:~/some-scripts$ ./test_mult_100.sh
execution time was -735035957 s.
```

I'm executing the .sh script on a computer through SSH via PuTTY. What's really strange to me is that I can obtain a negative number even after 3+ seconds of performing the intermediate operation. I unset the start_time and end_time variables to try and avoid overlapping values, though I don't think not doing so would cause an issue regardless.

Comment: Probably the numbers are too big for `expr`? The positive results look wrong, too.

Comment: I hadn't even considered it, but that totally makes sense. I'll try changing the nano seconds into milliseconds and see if it works better then.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm still getting the errors. It seems that the $(date -u +%N) part isn't as consistent as I want it to be. When I try dividing that value by 1000000 (turning the value into milliseconds), not only do I still occasionally get negative values, but occasionally I get the error message: "value too great for base". I tried doing so with this code:
start_time=$(($(date +%N)/1000000))
I think I will try an approach that doesn't use date.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`%N` is the number of nanoseconds into the current second.

It's not the number of nanoseconds since the epoch.

Comment: This is true, and at the core of the issue. After this I searched this issue again, and found a post on Stack Exchange (so not Stack Overflow, but related). Their post, located here: http://superuser.com/questions/599072/bash-execution-time-in-milliseconds-mac-osx-user, was geared towards Mac users, but is sufficient to answer my problem.

Comment: I realized I should probably also post my answer. Essentially, I added  %s to retrieving the timestamp to obtain the seconds since the epoch. The %N afterwards then gets it in nanoseconds.
Ex: start_time=$(date -u +%s%N)